# Trouble with bundle exec padrino start

Tags: ruby, bundle, rack, padrino

I am having difficulty performing a task which up until now has run without issue for the past year. To develop my Ruby Padrino application on my machine. I would use vagrant. Once vagrant is up I load the settings in putty and perform "bundle exec padrino start -h 0.0.0.0". This usually lead to the environment loading however after restarting my computer I now receive this error:

```
RuntimeError: Rack config file `0.0.0.0` must have `.ru` extension
  detect_application at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/padrino-core-0.12.4/lib/padrino-core/server.rb:23
                run! at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/padrino-core-0.12.4/lib/padrino-core/server.rb:12
               start at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/padrino-core-0.12.4/lib/padrino-core/cli/adapter.rb:7
               start at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/padrino-core-0.12.4/lib/padrino-core/cli/launcher.rb:30
                 run at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27
      invoke_command at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126
            dispatch at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359
               start at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440
              (root) at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/padrino-core-0.12.4/bin/padrino:9
                load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087
              (root) at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/bin/padrino:23
```

I also had to run bundle install prior to this so am wondering is it an updated gem file causing this issue or something else. Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command will execute as expected if you have it in quotes:

`bundle exec 'padrino start -h 0.0.0.0'`

The bug in Bundler is known and reported in issue https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4480

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I had to revert the version of Bundler from 1.12.0 to 1.11.2. Dont know what has changed but if anyone can shed some light on it I would appreciate it.